# Active directory with Asp.net windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have setup Active Directory in a VM and added some users into it. I used Windows 2008 core edition to setup the AD. Now to test my asp.net application, I created a sample page and configured in IIS. So when we call this page windows security window will be called and ask for username and passowrd.

My requirement is type the username and password which i specified inside AD. I provide username in the security window, something like:

```
test.ca/username
```

where `test.ca` is the domain name for AD. My problem is username is not getting accessed from VM and authentication fails and the username/pwd window prompts again.

Any one has suggestions?

Regards
Sangeetha

Answer (score 0):

The machine running IIS must be joined to the Active Directory domain in order to use Integrated authentication with domain accounts.

If the machine running IIS *cannot* be joined to the domain, then you would need to use Forms authentication instead.  Then, your ASP.NET application could, for example, validate the user's credentials against AD using the classes in the [System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) namespace.

Comment: Hi David, One quick question around the same area. I am planning to use custom AD URL for windows authentication. I currently do not see any option to implement it using Windows Authentication, is it recommended to use Forms Authentication and custom AD calls for actual authentication in this case?